# Can you make electromagnets with conductive plasma?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

So plasma is conductive, is it possible to wrap a plasma containing tube into a solenoid and use the conductive plasma as an electromagnet?

Comment: If a net current flows, sure. The problem is to keep the plasma a plasma.

Comment: Why would you wish to do it? Usually you are happy to have plasma for a short time.

Answer (score 5):

Plasma current provides the poloidal field component in a [tokamak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak).

A magnetic field produced by the current through a plasma pinches the flame, producing the sound of a [flame loudspeaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phG3PnyQ2dQ). Made one of those over half a century ago.